# Application level menu configurable at router/controller level

Tags: ember.js, handlebars.js

I've an Ember.js where I wish to have a menu "bar" at the application template (or a partial template). The menu is generic but has a couple options/properties that should be controlled by the router or controller, for example, some routes like login shouldn't show a "go back" button.

I also wish to avoid boilerplate at the router or controller levels but I'm finding the solution I've devised to be less than ideal. Here's what I did:

```
controllers/application.js:
showBackButton: function() {
    var v = this.controllerFor(this.currentRouteName).get('showBackButton');

    return (Ember.isEmpty(v) ? true : v);
}.property()
```

And because the templates wouldn't update between route changes:

```
routes/application.js:
didTransition: function() {
    this.controller.propertyDidChange('showBackButton');

    return true;
}
```

This allows me to define a new value for the property at a controller and it works. But I've 2 problems:

1. Ember 1.7 shows a deprecation warning for the controllerFor method, which I understand the new "needs" feature is replacing but in this case what is the alternative!?
2. Only the deepest controller can have the property, somehow I should transverse the hierarchy of controllers until I find it.

Is there a better way, without needing to add code to every template/controller or using base classes for those?

Answer (score 0):

Probably you can manage it on route-level?
Since relevant is the active route, not the controller.

[I have built an example on jsbin.](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/zexavobejo/1/edit?js,console,output)

I think u should handle a property on the `ApplicationController`. You can use the `willTransition` and `didTransition` hooks to set the property depending on your current controller. The rest is custom code depending on your exactly needs.

Comment: Well, that's what I initially had but it requires me to put logic in the controllers (didTransition) which is one of the things I want to avoid. If the logic changes I would need to patch every single usage or that code. Also, it still uses controllerFor which in your sample code could actually be migrated to use the *needs* property.

Comment: @AlexandreGomes you have the logic in the Routes, not in the Controller! And you need `controllerFor` since you dont have `needs` for Routes. And if you want a single point for that code, use a mixin!